# Ember: willTransition "Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to implement willTransition action in combination with a custom modal. My code is below:

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Please save your changes before you leave page.
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="stay" data-dismiss="modal">Stay</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="leave" data-dismiss="modal">Leave</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Route

```
actions: {      
    willTransition(transition) {
        var self = this;
        if (self.controller.get('changesNotSaved')) {

            transition.abort();

            Ember.$('#confirmModal').modal();
            Ember.$('#leave').on('click', function(){
                Ember.self.transitionTo(transition.handlerInfos[1].name);
            });
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }               
    },   
}
```

My problem is that I cannot redirect the user when he selects the "leave" button of the modal. I get the error

> Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined

I have read in the documantation page that calling transitionTo from within willTransition is feasible http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition.

I really don't know how to solve this... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where did you see the use of `Ember.self` but it's the first time I see it, and obviously the error comes because `Ember.self` is `undefined`.

Since you're saving the context of the function (that's it, the value of the `this` variable) at the beginning, if you just change `Ember.self` for `self` it should work.

Another, more modern approach, is using an arrow function because arrow functions preserves the caller context:

```js
Ember.$('#leave').on('click', () => {
    this.transitionTo(transition.handlerInfos[1].name);
});
```

With this technique you can remove the `var self = this;` line at the beginning.

You can learn more about arrow functions and its context preservation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

I recommend you to take some lectures about how Javascript works, because this pattern is something you will deal with constantly in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.The use of arrow function solved the error appearance but the functionality is still not right. When I click the "leave" button I stay in the same page. It seems like transitionTo doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Should not be there `this` instead of `Ember.self`?

```
Ember.$('#leave').on('click', function(){
    this.transitionTo(transition.handlerInfos[1].name);
});
```

I have never seen `Ember.self` and I guess that's the reason why it is undefined...

Comment: You are inside a click's callback, this refers to the dom node that was clicked, the node has no `transitionTo`.